# Why is this method behaving as virtual when its not marked as virtual?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following code

```
class base
{
    public:
    virtual void MyVirtual() { std::cout << "This is base MyVirtual \n";}
    void NonVirtual()        { std::cout << "This is base NonVirtual \n";}
};

class derA : public base
{
    public:
    void MyVirtual()  { std::cout << "This is derA MyVirtual \n";}
    void NonVirtual() { std::cout << "This is derA NonVirtual \n";}
};


class derB : public derA
{
    public:
    void MyVirtual()  { std::cout << "This is derB MyVirtual \n";}
    void NonVirtual() { std::cout << "This is derB NonVirtual \n";}
};

int main()
{
    derA *da = new derB;
    da->MyVirtual();     // "This is derB MyVirtual \n"
    da->NonVirtual();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is why is MyVirtual Method behaving as virtual when it is not marked as virtual in class `derA` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ inherited virtual functions remain virtual in the derived class even without the `virtual` keyword. It is considered good practice to write `virtual` for every inherited function.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments in C++ 11 it is considered good practice to include the keyword `override` immediately after the declarator. This catches a common class of errors and explicitly makes the intention clear in the code.

Comment: NOTE: in C++11 you should use `override`

Comment: derB b;
b.MyVirtual();
Now you call method of class dderB, when ypu create object polymorphism does not play its role :)

Comment: @AliKazmi I'm not following you. Your example is behaving correctly. When you write `A a = new B;` you are accessing B's MyVirtual method through a (this is standard polymorphism). And when you write `B b; b.MyVirtual()` There is no inheritance and you get B's behavior anyway.

Comment: polyphorism is attained by using the pointer of base class pointing to object of derieved, this is binded dynamically, but when you create object like A a;, a is created statically and hence will not able to call methods of base :)

Answer (score 3):

As per the Standard § 10.3 Point #2

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list ,
>   cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is
>   declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so
>   declared) and it overrides Base::vf.

There goes your answer, straight from the standards. So, it doesn't matter if you have used the keyword `virtual` in your derived class or not.